# free(): double free detected in tcache 2 Aborted

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void ffree(char **pp)
{
    if (!pp)
        return;

    char **a = pp;

    while (*pp) {
        free(*pp);  // Free the memory pointed to by pp
        pp++;       // Move to the next pointer
    }

    free(a); // Finally, free the memory for the array of pointers
}

int main() {
    char *str1 = strdup("Hello");
    char *str2 = strdup("World");
    
    char *arr[] = {str1, str2};

    ffree(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

in the simple code snippet above I'm writing my own array of strings free function where I free the pointer to an array of strings

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several errors in your program:

First of all, you need to know that **you can only free dynamically allocated memory** (via `malloc()` for example), in your code you use `strdup()` which calls `malloc()`.

`char *arr[] = {str1, str2};` is not dynamically allocated, you can't free it.

Secondly, in C, double-dimensional character arrays are delimited by `NULL`. The following block of code therefore doesn't work, because in arr there is no NULL:

```c
while (*pp) {
    free(*pp);
    pp++;
}
```

For it to work, you need to add the `NULL` to the last "line" of your array:

```c
char *arr[] = {str1, str2, NULL};
```

Also, the `malloc()` function can fail and you need to systematically check that it doesn't return NULL, at the risk of getting a segfault, so you should do the following:

```c
char *str1, *str2;

if ((str1 = strdup("Hello") == NULL) {
    // Error handling
}

if ((str2 = strdup("World") == NULL) {
    // Error handling
}
```

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ffree(char **pp)
{
    if (!pp)
        return;

    size_t i = 0;

    while (pp[i]) {
        free(pp[i]);
        i++;
    }

    free(pp);
}

int main(void) {

    char *str1 = strdup("Hello");
    char *str2 = strdup("World");

   if (!str1 || !str2) {
        if (str1) {
            free(str1);
        }
        if (str2) {
            free(str2);
        }
        return (-1)
   }

    char **arr = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));

    if (!arr) {
        free(str1);
        free(str2);
        return (-1);
    }

    arr[0] = str1;
    arr[1] = str2;
    arr[2] = NULL;

    ffree(arr);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: _"secondly, in C, double-dimensional character arrays are delimited by NULL. "_: this statement is wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky By convention, moreover in its code it works like this.

Comment: And your corrected code is overly complicated....

Comment: @VirgilG. Tip: _null pointer_ test not needed. `if (str1) { free(str1);  }` can simplify to `free(str1);` as `free(0)` is OK.

Comment: @VirgilG. Might as well allocate all 3, then test: `char *str1 = strdup("Hello"); char *str2 = strdup("World"); char **arr = malloc(3 * sizeof arr[0]); if (!str1 || !str2 || !arr) { free(str1); free(str2); free(arr); return -1; } arr[0] = str1; arr[1] = str2; arr[2] = NULL; ffree(arr);  return 0;`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I know, but I show him how to do it if he doesn't know the size of his array in advance.

Comment: I see now the problem with my code was that the array was not dynamically allocated and there was no NULL value attached at its end. thank you all for your help^^

Answer (score 4):

Bug 1:

`char *arr[] = {str1, str2};` There is no NULL pointer sentinel value at the end of the array here.

Therefore this doesn't make any sense:

```
  while (*pp) {
    free(*pp);  // Free the memory pointed to by pp
    pp++;       // Move to the next pointer
```

Bug 2:

`free(a);` this was never allocated dynamically and therefore shouldn't be freed.

Comment: I see now the problem with my code was that the array was not dynamically allocated and there was no NULL value attached at its end. thank you all for your help^^